# Difference between return values int& and const int&

Tags: c++, constants

I have two functions.

```
int& abc()
const int& abc() const
```

What is the difference between these two functions? I have source code with a class inside in which these two functions are defined. Aren't these two functions ambiguous in that they have the exact definition? What exactly is the difference between these two?

Comment: _" What exactly is the difference between these two?"_ - One  is `const` qualified and the other is not.

Comment: You haven't shown us either of the function's definitions, and in any event, a function's definition does not affect overload resolution.

Comment: When two functions have the same exact definition, how can those be overloaded?

Comment: the 1st one returns a reference, the 2nd returns a const reference, besides the function is declared as const, which means that the function can't change any members of the class, except the mutable ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple program demonstrating the difference between the two:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
    int c;
    public:
    Foo() {
        c = 1;
    }
    int abc() {
        c++;
        cout << "non-const, c = " << c << endl;
        return c;
    }

    const int& abc() const {
        //c++; // compile-error, can't modify in a const function
        cout << "const, c = " << c << endl;
        return c;
    }
};

int main() {
    const Foo foo1;
    Foo foo2;

    int a = foo1.abc();
    int b = foo2.abc();

    cout << "a = " << a << endl;
    cout << "b = " << b << endl;

    a++; b++;

    cout << "a = " << a << endl;
    cout << "b = " << b << endl;

    cout << foo1.abc() << endl;
    cout << foo2.abc() << endl;
}
```

The output is

> ```
> const, c = 1
> non-const, c = 2
> a = 1
> b = 2
> a = 2
> b = 3
> const, c = 1
> 1
> non-const, c = 3
> 3
> ```

The first function is allowed to modify the member variable `c`, whereas the second cannot. The appropriate function is called depending on `const` qualification.

It is common to have a function paired with a `const` qualified version of it. See, for example, [`operator[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator%5B%5D/) for `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

A member function can be overloaded in its constness. So, the second member function overloads the first member function. They are not the same function. One is const and another isn't. 
This is usefull when you declare a constant object of a class. Constants objects can access ONLY const member functions. So, you have a const member function declared for this case.

```
class MyClass {
    int nr;
    public:
       MyClass (int value) : nr (value) {}
       int& getNr () {return nr;} // this will be called by a non constant obj
       conts int& getNr () const {return nr;} // this one will be 
          // called by a constant object
}

int main () {
    MyClass foo (1);
    const MyClass bar (2);

    // Here int& getNr () {} will be called
    cout << foo.getNr () << endl; 

    // And here const int& getNr () const {} will be called
    cout << bar.getNr () << endl;

    return 0;
}
```